# Return reference to sliced object (supertype)

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference, object-slicing

Consider the following classes:

```
class Coord
{
public:
    double _x, _y;

    Coord(double x, double y)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }
};

class NamedPoint : public Coord
{
public:
    int _id;

    NamedPoint(int id, double x, double y) :
        Coord(x,y),
        _id(id)
    {
    }
};
```

I'd like to create a member function of NamedPoint -- coord() -- that returns a reference of type Coord corresponding to the NamedPoint.

For example, I'd like to something like:

```
const Coord& NamedPoint::coord()
{
    return ((Coord)*this);
}
```

But I get a warning about temporary variables and I'm not crazy about it.

Of course, the following works:

```
Coord coord()
{
    Coord c = *this;
    return c;
}
```

But I'd rather return a reference.

Does anyone know if this is possible using inherited classes?

Sorry for not explaining the point of the function.  I'm overloading the == operator differently for Coord and NamedPoint.  Coord would simply check {x,y} and NamedPoint would check {id,x,y}.  If I forget to cast a NamedPoint to a Coord before this == test, I'll use the wrong version.

So, while I realize that

```
(Coord)np1 == (Coord)np2
```

would give me what I want, I'd rather use something like

```
np1.coord() == np2.coord()
```

which I think is more clear as to what is going on.

Comment: you don't seem to be noticing/acknowledging the difference between converting to `Coord`, which copies part of the object, vs converting to `Coord&`, which creates a reference to the base class sub-object of your point. GMan's solution does the latter, all the code you've written does the former, and that's why you got warnings in your first `coord()` function. You said "I'd rather return a reference", but you returned a reference to a (partial) copy, not to the original. Then `(Coord)np1 == (Coord)np2` comparies copies too. Whichever way you do it, copying is needless.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  In fact, the difference is why I asked the question in the first place.  I was looking for a way to obtain a reference to the base class sub-object (which was nicely put by the way) -- and the only solutions I could come up with were ones that made copies of the sub-object.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's the point of the function? `NamedPoint` is implicitly convertible to `Coord` anyway:

```
void foo(Coord& c)
{
    c._x = 5;
}

NamedCoord nc(0, 1, 2);
foo(nc); // c references the Coord part of nc
```

Anyway, your function should simply use this conversion:

```
const Coord& NamedPoint::coord()
{
    // Bad: takes the value of *this and slices off
    // the derived bits, leaving a temporary Coord.
    /* return ((Coord)*this); */

    // Good: takes the value of *this and refers
    // to the base bits, no temporaries.
    return *this;

    // (Same as:)
    /* return ((Coord&)*this); */
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about the point -- its really more of a "philosophical"-type thing -- I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks -- I don't think I was aware of the cast-to-reference sort of syntax (Coord&).  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

@GMan gives the main solution.

However, it might be interesting to note in more detail the problem:

```
const Coord& NamedPoint::coord()
{
    return ((Coord)*this);
}
```

This is much the same as:

```
const Coord& NamedPoint::coord()
{
    Coord c = *this;
    return c;
}
```

Here it is clear that you are returning a reference to a temporary on the stack, which makes the reference to it useless, and hence the warning.

Now in the case presented, `Coord` is the base class and hence we have the simple solution given by @Gman.

In the general case, the principle is that if you want a reference to `something`, you better make sure that `something` will still be around.

Comment: Thank you, I had thought this is what was meant by the warning.